# How to update values from a JSON input

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, replace

I had another question that I ended up solving myself where I take a JSON input that has names and IP addresses. Then I resolve those IP addresses by looping through and need to replace the IP address with the resolve FQDN if there is one

I have no idea how to update/replace these values from the original JSON. I’ve read that arrays cannot be changed, only added to. This is where I’m stuck as I can get my script to write-out the resolve FQDN is there was one or the IP if there wasn’t... but I can’t get these values to replace the original value from the JSON with the ultimate goal to then take the newly modified JSON and upload it as a new config

Sample JSON input

```
{
  "entry": [
    {
      "@name": "31.170.162.203",
      "ip-netmask": "31.170.162.203",
      "description": "test1"
    },
    {
      "@name": "37.193.217.222",
      "ip-netmask": "37.193.217.222",
      "description": "test2"
    },
    {
      "@name": "46.17.63.169",
      "ip-netmask": "46.17.63.169",
      "description": "test3"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
$input = Get-Content 'C:\Users\e\Desktop' -raw | ConvertFrom-Json

$iplist = $input.entry.'ip-netmask'


foreach ($ip in $iplist)   #for each line in the file...

{
    $hostnames = $null

    try {

        $hostnames = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress("$ip").Hostname   #...resolve the ip

    }
     catch [System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException] {

          $hostnames = "Server IP cannot resolve."
    }

    catch {

        $hostnames = "unknown error."

    }

    if ($hostnames -ne "Server IP cannot resolve.") {

        $ip -replace $ip, $hostnames

    } else {

        Write-Host $ip
    }
}
```

Comment: First, stop misusing [automatic variable `$input`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json had an extra comma.  I would do it this way.  A property with a dash is harder to work with.

```
$a = cat file.json | convertfrom-json
$a.entry | foreach { 
  if ($namehost = (resolve-dnsname $_.'ip-netmask').namehost ) { # not null
    $_.'ip-netmask' = $namehost 
  } 
}
$a.entry

@name          ip-netmask                     description
-----          ----------                     -----------
31.170.162.203 31.170.162.203                 test1
37.193.217.222 l37-193-217-222.novotelecom.ru test2
46.17.63.169   46.17.63.169                   test3
```

This is sort of like saying:

```
$namehost = (resolve-dnsname $_.'ip-netmask').namehost
if ($namehost -ne $null) { # ...
# or 
if ($namehost) { # ...
```

but I'm doing the assignment and testing the value of the assignment at the same time, like in C.  An assignment can be an expression.

```
$a = ($b = 1)
```

Then I'm going through the "entry" array and assigning each 'ip-netmask' property to the results if they aren't null.

Comment: Ok...this seems to work in that it only replaces the ip-netmask field's ip with a DNS name if there is one. I'm unclear how it's working in the loop. Can you explain the logic in it?

Comment: I did overlook one thing.... to use an FQDN the entry.’ip-netmask’ must be changed to entry.’fqdn’. Config won’t take otherwise. I tried to add $a.entry.’ip-netmask’ = $a.entry.’fqdn’ below where netmask is set to the namehost, but that didn’t work

Comment: So to clarify, it looks like if there’s an fqdn, I want to rename the ‘ip-netmask’ array property to ‘fqdn’ also

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet could help:

```
$Json = @'
{
    "entry":[
        {
            "@name":"31.170.162.203",
            "ip-netmask":"31.170.162.203",
            "description":"test1"
        },
        {
            "@name":"37.193.217.222",
            "ip-netmask":"37.193.217.222",
            "description":"test2"
        },
        {
            "@name":"46.17.63.169",
            "ip-netmask":"46.17.63.169",
            "description":"test3"
        }
    ]
}
'@  | ConvertFrom-Json
for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $Json.entry.Count; $i++ ) {
    $entry = $Json.entry[$i]
    $ip = $entry.'ip-netmask'
    $hostnames = $null
    try {
        $hostnames = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress("$ip").Hostname   #...resolve the ip
        $entry.'ip-netmask' = $hostnames
    }
     catch [System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException] {
          $hostnames = "Server IP cannot resolve."
    }
    catch {
        $hostnames = "unknown error."
    }
    Write-Host $entry.'@name', $hostnames -ForegroundColor Cyan
}
### debugging output:
$Json.entry
### final conversion hinted:
### $Json | ConvertTo-Json
###
```

Note that I use a [here-string](https://powershell.org/2019/04/hear-hear-for-here-strings/) instead of (probably incorrect)

```
Get-Content 'C:\Users\e\Desktop' -raw
```

Comment: Haven’t been able to try this yet, but why are you putting the JSON directly in the script? My real data that’s in the format I originally posted has over 6000 lines. Copy/pasting is not ideal, so I’m wondering what the reason is.

Comment: I used that here-string as **1.**  I don't have a file `'C:\Users\e\Desktop'` (or even a folder `C:\Users\e\`), and **2.** I don't want to create such things on my `C:` drive, and **3.** I noticed it already in my answer…